# Is it possible to update cell in excel file located in SharePoint library With Javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, excel

I wonder if it's possible to change/Update a cell value in Excel file located in SharePoint online using Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Excel REST APIs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/discovery-in-excel-services-rest-api). For Office 365 Education, Business, and Enterprise accounts, use the [Excel REST APIs that are part of the Microsoft Graph endpoin](https://dev.office.com/blogs/additions-to-excel-rest-api-on-microsoft-graph)t to read and modify an excel file.

For example, update cells in range:

```
PATCH /{version}/me/drive/items/01CYZLFJDYBLIGAE7G5FE3I4VO2XP7BLU4/workbook/worksheets('test')/range(address='test!A1:B2')
{ "values": [ [ "Test", "Value" ], [ "For", "Update" ] ] }
```

Another method, you could read/write xlsx file by some js library, for example [xlsx-populate](https://github.com/dtjohnson/xlsx-populate).